# Should I use mod_fastcgi or mod_fcgid for PHP and Django?

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I would like to use FastCGI to host the program, what are the differences between mod_fastcgi and mod_fcgid? How to decide which to use?

Comment: [What's the difference between “mod_fastcgi” and “mod_fcgid”?](http://superuser.com/questions/228173/whats-the-difference-between-mod-fastcgi-and-mod-fcgid)